# Expected FS format ‘2’; found format ‘3’

Tags: ssh, svn, version-control

I've seen a good amount of articles dealing with older svn versions hitting this problem, but my situation is as follows.

I am using Subversion 1.6.6

I have 'versions', a mediocre mac svn gui, which uses the command line svn tools (version 1.6.6)! My repo (svnserve v1.6.6) is located on a max box on my local network, I'm accessing it via svn+ssh.

The box that hosts the repo (also up to date on svn v1.6.6) can connect via file:// but not via ssh://

The repo was created with versions on the host and worked reliably for some time. I'm not sure what the tipping point was, but it may have been me creating a second user specifically for ssh connections. Now the repo cannot be accessed from either user via ssh.

here is the command line attempt..

```
user$ svn up
svn: Expected FS format '2'; found format '3'
user$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053)
compiled Oct 22 2009, 14:13:09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your repository URL?

The reason I ask is that you mention connecting via SSH, which I will assume to mean a "svn+ssh" style URL. If that's the case, then you should check the version of *svnserve* running on the server machine:

```
ssh SERVER svnserve --version
```

You'll note that I'm executing the command directly from ssh. This should ensure that the environment is set up just as it would be when svn executes the same command (whereas a login shell might do something different).

Assuming that you find that the server is running an outdated version of svnserve, next task is to find out where it is (so that you can delete it):

```
ssh SERVER which svnserve
```